# How to pass string to separate java.class

Tags: java, android, string, class, variables

I'm trying to pass a string from my main activity to a separate class
that does not have a activity running.

I've looked into passing variables with intent and bundles but what i've read they use two activities

I've found a video of something close to what i'm trying to do but in reverse and can't get it to work. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSifkubnE-E)

Now the string changes so I can't use static
and my second.java has no context to pass to.

below is a basic representation of what i'd would like to do.

main.java

```
    import second

    public class Main extends Activity {
        String mystring = "variable"
        //mystring changes depending on the user
        mystring = "userchangedvariable"
    }
```

second.java

```
    public class dosomething(){
        String localvar;
        localvar = mystring
    }
```

To be clear as possible I want to pass a variable from the main.java to the second.java that has no context. I don't want to add the second.java class to my main.java, I want to keep them separate(some of the things I read say merge them). How can I do this?

Comment: What's your definition of "separate"? No compile time dependency between them? No instance creation of second in main? Second... why? If you are sharing data between them, there is a dependency, regardless of how you decide to pass the data.

Comment: took a little while but i understood what you said and made some changes to the handle thread and construct works now thank you. 10 days into android developing there is sooo much to absorb and should not be rushed it makes dumb mistakes like this one!

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the following statement.

> Now the string changes so I can't use static

You can update the `static` values. You cannot update `final` values. Also, you need to somehow create a connection. You can create another class and share the static variables

```
class ThirdClass {
        public static String sharedString;
    }

    class Main {
        ThirdClass.sharedString = "somevalue";
    }

    class Second {
        localVar = ThirdClass.sharedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in those ways:

```
class Activity {
    onCreate() {
        String stringToPass = "TEST";
        Example example = new Example(stringToPass);
    }
}

class Example {
    private String stringToPass;

    public Example(String stringToPass) {
        this.stringToPass = stringToPass;
    }
}

or

class Activity {
    onCreate() {
        String stringToPass = "TEST";
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setStringToPass(stringToPass);
    }
}

class Example {
    private String stringToPass;

    public void setStringToPass(String stringToPass) {
        this.stringToPass = stringToPass;
    }

    public Example() {
    }
}

or

class Activity {
    onCreate() {
        String stringToPass = "TEST";
        Example.stringToPass = stringToPass;
    }
}

static class Example {
    public static String stringToPass;
}

or (not the advised way)


class Activity {
    onCreate() {
        String stringToPass = "TEST";
        Example example = new Example();
        example.stringToPass = stringToPass;
    }
}

class Example {
    public String stringToPass;

    public Example() {
    }
}
```

If you create a new object and the string is required for creating -> great make it as a requirement in the constructor. (first version)

If you create a new object and the string is not required for creating -> great make a property (second version)

Third version is needed more rarely (you can set the string without having to create an object) and the fourth version should be avoided completely in Java.

Answer (score -1):

In the main `.java` file, add the following:

```
second example = new second("variable");
```

This can then be referenced anywhere inside your main method. For example:

```
example.setString("variable);
```

Then, inside your second `.java` file, you'll need to add the following:

```
public class second

{

   private String variable;

   public void setString(String pass)

   {

   variable = pass

   }

}
```

This way anything you pass to the example variable inside your main `.java` file
will be passed over to the `setString` method.